# Unable to read shape file in Android

Tags: android, maps, arcgis

I am trying to use ShapefileFeatureTable() to read shape file in android. No matter what path I give, it says, "File Not Found" exception.

```
try 
{
    ShapefileFeatureTable shpFileFeatTable = new ShapefileFeatureTable("/storage/sdcard/map.shp");
} 
catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
{
    e.printStackTrace();
} 
catch(Exception e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Can anyone help me?

Note: I am working on Android Emulator. Also I am using arcGIS library.

Comment: try getting path using `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out, it was displaying the shapefile. I had to blank the MapView to see it.

```
<com.esri.android.map.MapView
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
</com.esri.android.map.MapView>
```

Comment: You had to *blank* the MapView? What does that mean? And how does this fix your FileNotFoundException when loading the shapefile?

Answer (score 0):

see this example if helps you

> https://developers.arcgis.com/android/api-reference/reference/com/esri/core/geodatabase/ShapefileFeatureTable.html

Answer (score 0):

Your app is probably not requesting permission to read from external storage. You need to put the following in AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

At the moment, a [ShapefileFeatureTable](https://developers.arcgis.com/android/api-reference/reference/com/esri/core/geodatabase/ShapefileFeatureTable.html)  is read-only, but if this class gets editing capabilities in the future and you want to do editing, your app will need to request write permissions as well:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

See http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-permission-element.html for more details.

It's also possible (but not likely) that your file path is simply incorrect. If you request read permissions and still get the `FileNotFoundException`, check the value of `new File("/path/to/file.shp").exists()`. If Android can't see the file, ArcGIS can't see the file either.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem. Be sure that other files related to map.shp there are beside of it on same folder. Extensions of other files related to map.shp are: .dbf .prj .sbn .sbx .shp.xml .shx